# Concept about create a hierarchy of mail group Office365 on excel with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, office365, concept

i need a concept help about a script that need to do the following works:

**IMPORTANT: I don't want that you write for me the script, only help me understand the ways to do it!**

In my workplace we have 180 users and 125 distribution groups.
the user and the distribution group are nested in they self.

```
i.e. Company Group -> Company IT -> ICT -> User1
            "             "          "  -> User2
            "             "      -> HR  -> User3
            "             "          "  -> User4
            "      -> Company FR -> Res -> User5
            "             "      -> User6
```

So every Distributiongroup can have either other group or user inside.
There is the possibility that group haven't no user inside like the possibility that user are in no group.

I create a Script that read every user and every group and log me for every user which group contain it but it works obviously only for the last group they are.

```
i.e. Group 1 -> Group 2 -> Group 3 -> User 1
```

the script write me

```
 User 1 are in:
 Group 3
```

I need a more "intelligent" and complex script.
It need to do everything by its own and learn the hierarchy without no user help.
The final result is an Excel file reporting everything like first Code windows I write.

Many thanks to everyone help me, no matter if only a bit.

**Edit:**

I add here the previous script for help you understand.

```
############################################
# Filling variables
############################################

Write-Host "Download Distribution Group list..."
$gruppi = Get-DistributionGroup | Sort-Object DisplayName
Write-Host "Download MSOL User list..."
$utenti = Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.isLicensed -eq 'True'}
$utenti = $utenti.userprincipalname 
$utenti = $utenti | Sort-Object
$filePath = "c:\UtentiNoGruppoLOG2.txt"
$utentisenzagruppo = @()
$matrixutentigruppi = @()

foreach ($gruppo in $gruppi) {
    Write-host "Downloading $($gruppo.DisplayName) member list..."
    $matrixutentigruppi += ,@($gruppo,(Get-DistributionGroupMember -identity $gruppo.PrimarySmtpAddress))
}

############################################
# Check existing log file
############################################

cls

If (Test-Path $filePath) {
    $confCancellazione = Read-Host "`nFile Log già presente, eliminarlo? (Y/N)"
    If ($confCancellazione -eq 'y') {
        Remove-Item $filePath
    }
}

############################################
# Main
############################################

cls

foreach ($utente in $utenti) {
    $voidControl = 0
    write-host "`n$($utente.ToUpper()) è nei seguenti gruppi:"
    write-output "`r`n$($utente.ToUpper()) è nei seguenti gruppi:" >> $filePath
    foreach ($matrixutentigruppo in $matrixutentigruppi) {
        $mailgruppo = $($matrixutentigruppo[0].PrimarySmtpAddress)
        if ($($matrixutentigruppo.PrimarySmtpAddress) -contains $utente) {
            $voidControl = 1
            Write-host "$($matrixutentigruppo[0].DisplayName) `($mailgruppo`)"
            write-output "$($matrixutentigruppo[0].DisplayName) `($mailgruppo`)" >> $filePath
        }
    }

    # Check ugrouped users

    if ($voidControl -eq 0) {
        write-host "NESSUN GRUPPO!!!"
        write-output "NESSUN GRUPPO!!!" >> $filePath
        $utentisenzagruppo += "`r`n$utente"
    }
}

############################################
# Report ungrouped users
############################################

write-host "`r`nUtenti senza gruppi:"
write-output "`r`nUtenti senza gruppi:" >> $filePath
if (!$utentisenzagruppo) {
    write-host "`r`nNESSUN UTENTE E' SENZA GRUPPO!"
    write-output "`r`nNESSUN UTENTE E' SENZA GRUPPO!" >> $filePath
}
else {
    write-host "$utentisenzagruppo"
    write-output "$utentisenzagruppo" >> $filePath
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your current script, so we can identify where your logic is faulty. It looks like you are assigning the group membership to a variable inside a loop; instead, if you want ALL groups the user is in to be recorded, you should create an array outside of the loop, and add the groups to that array inside the loop.

Comment: I can post it but the current script do exactly what i want it do.
There is no error in it.
The new script want to be a more powerful tools that do a more complex analysis.

Comment: OK, re-reading your question and seeing your current script, I think I understand. I would approach this by using recursion -- create a powershell function that gets the members of a group, and if that member is itself a group, have it call the function again on that group. That should get you the raw data in such a way that you can output it to CSV, showing the hierarchy.

Comment: The problem using your way is that a member of a group don't seems have a propriety describing the groups it belongs, only the opposite, so only the group know his member. This is why I make the current script. If there was this propriety the current script would have been a 10 lines code: for all the user print property memberof.

Comment: Yes, but in your loop you know what group you are currently expanding. So add that as a NoteProperty or whatever.